# Bugzilla migration from ubuntu 10.04 to 14.04 with Mysql 5.1 to Mysql 5.5

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mysql5.5, bugzilla, mysql5.1

I am running Bugzilla 4.0 on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS running on physical server & thought of upgrading it to Ubuntu 14.04 on Hyper-V for testing.

After migration of bugzilla webroot 4.0 to Ubuntu 14.04 with MySql 5.1 server to MySql 5.5 & other required application & it started working properly.

But when I deep dived in testing of bugzilla, I found everything synced except bugs which are created by users, but the total count is showed in "Edit Products" section.

Old Server Details:
OS: Ubuntu 10.04, Apache2.2, Mysql-Server-5.1, php5

New Server Details:
OS: Ubuntu 14.04, Apache2.4.7, Mysql-Server-5.5-49, php5.5.9

PS: Everything was working in test machine, after upgrading below packages, the issue started.

```
mysql-server-core-5.5:amd64 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
mysql-server-5.5:amd64 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
mysql-client-core-5.5:amd64 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), 
libapache2-mod-php5:amd64 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14, 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.16)
php5-mysql:amd64 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14, 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.16)
dpkg:amd64 (1.17.5ubuntu5.5, 1.17.5ubuntu5.6)
php5-common:amd64 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14, 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.16)
dpkg-dev:amd64 (1.17.5ubuntu5.5, 1.17.5ubuntu5.6)
php5-readline:amd64 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14, 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.16)
php5:amd64 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14, 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.16)
mysql-client-5.5:amd64 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
mysql-common:amd64 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
libdpkg-perl:amd64 (1.17.5ubuntu5.5, 1.17.5ubuntu5.6)
php5-cli:amd64 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14, 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.16)
libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
tzdata:amd64 (2016c-0ubuntu0.14.04, 2016d-0ubuntu0.14.04)
mysql-server:amd64 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
php5-gd:amd64 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14, 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.16)
libpcre3:amd64 (8.31-2ubuntu2.2, 8.31-2ubuntu2.3)
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue.

Actual Problem matches to this.
[bugs are not showing up (show up in DB and everything seems to be fine) | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701792/bugzilla-bugs-are-not-showing-up-show-up-in-db-and-everything-seems-to-be-fine)

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is? Can you give more details about exactly what's wrong?

Comment: Yes, reloaded mysql db & bugzilla webroot reloaded to test machine from production for testing, but when I search its not showing up, in same time when I search with status:ALL & Product:ALL I am able to see bugs, but the bugs which are create by user are not visible to users. As an admin, I can see all bugs as I do search with said above.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with groups and permissions, but there's no way to tell more specifically without more information.

Comment: The user is admin for the bugzilla project instance. he has all rights. Please let me know what more information you need.

Comment: Screenshots are here.

https://www.sendspace.com/file/pysg2g
https://www.sendspace.com/file/hrs0dc
https://www.sendspace.com/file/7lcgpj
https://www.sendspace.com/file/80xp6h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow!!!! Finally Migrated.

Downloaded new version of Bugzilla 5.0.1 & patched with 5.0.2. On Mysql 5.5.49 imported DB. Linked with the Bugzilla instance with appropriate access to & run checksetup.pl, It did migrated & removed & added unsupported UTF-8 fields & ready with new version of Bugzilla 5.0.2.

Thanks for help buddies.